# Rails: how to require at least one field not to be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, models

I know I can require a field by adding `validates_presence_of :field` to the model. However, how do I require at least one field to be mandatory, while not requiring any particular field?

thanks in advance

-- Deb

Comment: I believe you'll have to write your own validation

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use:

```
validate :any_present?

def any_present?
  if %w(field1 field2 field3).all?{|attr| self[attr].blank?}
    errors.add :base, "Error message"
  end
end
```

EDIT: updated from original answer for Rails 3+ as per comment.

But you have to provide field names manually.
You could get all content columns of a model with `Model.content_columns.map(&:name)`, but it will include `created_at` and `updated_at` columns too, and that is probably not what you want.

Comment: To update this answer for Rails 3, use `errors.add :base, "Error Message"` as add_to_base is deprecated

Answer (score 9):

Here's a reusable version:

```
class AnyPresenceValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    unless options[:fields].any?{|attr| record[attr].present?}
      record.errors.add(:base, :blank)
    end
  end
end
```

You can use it in your model with:

```
validates_with AnyPresenceValidator, fields: %w(field1 field2 field3)
```

Comment: Instead of pairing `all?` with `blank?` here, you could also pair `any?` with `present?` so that the code itself follows the semantics of the validator name

Answer (score 8):

Add a `validate` method to your model:

```
def validate
  if field1.blank? and field2.blank? and field3.blank? # ...
    errors.add_to_base("You must fill in at least one field")
  end
end
```

Comment: I can't imagine he would want to check if one field _in his entire model_ is present. I assumed it was a particular set of fields.

Comment: your answer is also correct, so I voted it up as well. However, I ended up using Voyta's answer. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @RobertSpeicher I do agree with you since, usually, we would like to check if one-of-the-two are present. Such: (phone or email) or (deadline or date in arrears) not requiring only one field out of the 10 or... So, I voted for your answer for it's simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

I believe something like the following may work

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   validate do |my_model|
      my_model.my_validation
   end

   def my_validation      
      errors.add_to_base("Your error message") if self.blank? 
      #or self.attributes.blank? - not sure
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Going further with @Votya's correct answer, here is a way to retrieve all columns besides created_at and updated_at (and optionally, any others you want to throw out):

```
# Get all column names as an array and reject the ones we don't want
Model.content_columns.map(&:name).reject {|i| i =~ /(created|updated)_at/}
```

For example:

```
 1.9.3p327 :012 > Client.content_columns.map(&:name).reject {|i| i =~ /(created|updated)_at/}
 => ["primary_email", "name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two fields, this will get the job done:

```
validates :first_name, presence: true, if: :nick_name.blank?
validates :nick_name, presence: true, if: :first_name.blank?
```

This does not scale up well with more fields, but when you only have two, this is perhaps clearer than a custom validation method.

n.b. If they omit both, the error message will appear more restrictive than you intend. (e.g. `First Name is required. Nick Name is required.`)  ¯\*(ツ)*/¯