# Rails 3: how to require at least one field not to be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model that has several properties. I want to validate that at least one of those properties is set. I saw the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823628/rails-how-to-require-at-least-one-field-not-to-be-blank), but the *errors.add_to_base* is now deprecated in Rails 3 and was wondering what the new solution might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now simply

```
errors.add(:base, "message")
```