# How to use read_attribute when manually defining getter/setter (attr_accessor or attr_writers)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2, models

I set up a `search` model and want to require at least one field is filled out.  I found a question that helps with the validation, [Rails: how to require at least one field not to be blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823628/rails-how-to-require-at-least-one-field-not-to-be-blank).  (I tried all answers, but Voyta's seems the best.)

The validation is working, except when I want to redefine the getter/setter via `attr_accessor` or `attr_writer`.  (I have virtual attributes on the form that need to be apart of the validation.)  To figure out what the problem is, I tested with an attribute that is a regular attribute `item_length`.  If I add `attr_accessor :item_length`, the validation stops to work.  So, I guess the question is how to I read an attribute's value without using dot notation.  Since the validation uses strings, I can't use the normal way of reading.

Here is a snippet:

```
if %w(keywords 
      item_length 
      item_length_feet 
      item_length_inches).all?{|attr| read_attribute(attr).blank?}
    errors.add(:base, "Please fill out at least one field")
  end
```

Like I said, the virtual attrbutes (length_inches and length_feet) do not work at all, and the normal attribute (length) works except if I redefine the getter/setter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in comment, use `send`

```
array.all? {|attr| send(attr).blank?}
```

---

For those wondering if `send` is ok in this case, yes it is: object calls its own instance methods.

But `send` is a sharp tool, so whenever you use with other objects, ensure you use their public api with `public_send`

Comment: prefer `public_send` to respect encapsulation

Comment: @BrendanDean Which encapsulation? Everything happens within the same class, whats the problem? Using `public_send` would prevent instance from using some of its methods

Comment: I mean object encapsulation:  
"encapsulation…A language mechanism for restricting access to some of the object's components." - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)  
`send` ignores access specifiers like `private`.  
`send_public` respects them.

Comment: @BrendanDean Ok but within a class its useless, hopefuly you can call private methods within public methods

Comment: Basically a class encapsulates methods and properties, its exposes a public api. But the object itself, in its internals should not be restricted to the public api, it can access everything within itself. `send` is 100% legit here. It wouldnt be if you start using it to access one object internals from another class though

Comment: You're right. I'll switch to an upvote. 

I like to encourage use of `public_send` unless you *must* use `send`, because `public_send` has the correct default behavior. But that's a stylistic concern—your answer is correct.

Comment: ah I guess I need to edit, you should be good. I completely agree with you about the need to push people towards `public_send`

Answer (score 8):

You should consider read_attribute as a private method for reading Active Record columns. Otherwise you should always use readers directly.

```
self.read_attribute(:item_length) # does not work
self.item_length # ok
```

Since you are trying to call this dynamically, you can use generic ruby method `public_send` to call the specified method

```
self.public_send(:item_length) # the same as self.item_length
```

Comment: `public_send` works, also. I saw apneadiving's answer first, so I accepted that one.